# what is the special case that make `str1 == str2` a logical error?

Tags: java

I know that java stores `String Literals` in `Common Pool` and two string literals having the same text will refer to the same place in Common Pool. take below code:

```
String str1 = "Amir";
String str2 = "Amir";
```

now both `str1` and `str2`refer to the same place in the Common Pool. so from what all we know we must use equals() to properly compare these two strings and obviously `str1.equals(str2)` will be `true`.

now from what i read  [here](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html) it says that the `str1 == str2` will be true becuase the strings both have the same address (sounds pretty logical) but it also states that its a logical error to do so.

my question is what is that special case that may cuase trouble and inconsistency to my code if I use `str1 == str2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not *special* cases, *common* cases:

```
String base = "Amir123";
String str1 = base.substring(0, 4);
String str2 = "Amir";
System.out.println(str1.equals(str2)); // true
System.out.println(str1 == str2);      // false
```

[Live Copy](http://ideone.com/FmxVc2)

```
String str1 = "Amir";
String am = "Am";
String ir = "ir";
String str2 = am + ir;
System.out.println(str1.equals(str2)); // true
System.out.println(str1 == str2);      // false
```

[Live Copy](http://ideone.com/NTGlRC) *(thank you [JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945651/jlrishe))*

Basically, just about *any* time a string is created at runtime instead of being fully-formed at compile-time, by default it will be a new `String` object, and so not `==` another equivalent `String` object.

Comment: Also: http://ideone.com/NTGlRC

Comment: yes true. even this: http://ideone.com/jU4GAA